# Progress Bar For Compact Framework with RTL Layout

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I want to create Progress bar control for compact framework .Net 2.0 C# with Right to Left Layout property.
Please can one help me in creating this
Below is the link to progress bar custom control 
[Custom Progress Bar](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Custom-Colored-ProgressBar-a68b61de#content)

when I am using code of this referenced project it results into errors

Comment: You'll have to ask a more specific question, and at least include _which_ errors you're getting

Comment: e.Graphics.Transform = new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, Width, 0); In this line I am getting errors as e.Graphics does not contain definition of Transform Matrix is also not there for Compact Framework

Comment: I found this https://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/customprogressbar.aspx?fid=853291&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&view=Normal&fr=26#xx0xx but when setting target platform as windows CE throws error as Exception : Parameter is not valid

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help you with that, but it appears the author has used alot of `#if PocketPC` directives. Can you ensure that this symbol is set (project properties -> build -> conditional compilation symbols)? You should see the relevant parts of the code light up or be grayed out accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458186/right-to-left-layout-property-in-below-code this is more simple code the only thing is RTL missing can we add that please help